# POM parent artifact id same to original artifact is

Tags: maven, gradle

On our artifactory, we have POM file as

```
<parent>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>2.6</version>
 </parent>
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
 <version>2.6</version>
 <name>Commons Lang</name>
```

I get error as

```
[FATAL] 'parent.artifactId' must be changed, 
the parent element cannot have the same groupId:artifactId as the project.
```

But i get this error only when i use plugin 'io.spring.dependency-management'
Otherwise build runs fine. I believe root cause is this only it is causing cyclic dependency but why with this plugin only and not without it.

Answer (score 1):

That POM file is rubbish. You should remove it from the Artifactory.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the difference of using plugin  'io.spring.dependency-management'

Comment: I see, but I don't think it is worth the effort. You have a completely broken POM file. This could cause any kind of error (or not). It is like "If I divide by 0, I only get an error in case XY". I would advice not to divide by zero instead of "understanding" it.